# How to find out where an application is installed, on physical disk?

Tags: hard-disk, pci

The commands `whereis` and `dpkg -L` will help in finding out an application's location.

But I am trying to understand the physical location where the application is installed, like on drive `/dev/sda` or `/dev/sdb`...

I am working in a environment where my system/server is connected with 18 disks (without RAID or LVM in use), so trying to get the information physical drive for that particular application.

Comment: You can use `df` on the file and it will display the filesystem that it's on. eg `df -h /bin/ls`.

Comment: You've asked what is, in general, a very hard question because of various mappings between the filesystem and the disks: RAID, device-mapper (LVM), various SAN things, etc. Could you clarify which (if any) are in use on your server?

Comment: no RAID and LVM are applied currently on the server...

Comment: @jordanm since OP says there isn't RAID or LVM, you should make than an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tune this script a little to produce a nicer output:

```
APP='coreutils'
for x in $(dpkg -L "$APP"); do
  test -f "$x" && df "$x" |\
  grep -v '^Filesystem' |\
  awk '{printf "block_dev: %s, mount_point:%s\n", $1, $NF}'
done | sort -u
```